# Cross property validation using INotifyDataErrorInfo not working

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, inotifydataerrorinfo

I'm trying to implement validation in my MVVM project, with validation done at Model. Below is a minimal example:

View:

```
Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:VM x:Key="VM"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource VM}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Number: "/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Number, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
                 ToolTip="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Limit: "/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Limit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
                 ToolTip="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private Model _model = new Model();

    public int Number
    {
        get { return this._model.Number; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._model.Number)
                this._model.Number = value;
        }
    }

    public int Limit
    {
        get { return this._model.Limit; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._model.Limit)
                this._model.Limit = value;
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this._model.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(sender, args);
        this._model.ErrorsChanged += (sender, args) => this.ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }

    public bool HasErrors => this._model.HasErrors;

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName) => this._model.GetErrors(propertyName);
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private int _number;
    public int Number
    {
        get => _number;
        set
        {
            if (_number != value)
            {
                _number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                //ValidateNumber();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _limit;
    public int Limit
    {
        get => _limit;
        set
        {
            if (_limit != value)
            {
                _limit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                ValidateNumber();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ValidateNumber()
    {
        var propertyName = nameof(Number);
        if (Number > Limit)
            _errors[propertyName] = new[] { "Number cannot be larger than Limit." };
        else
        {
            if (_errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                _errors.Remove(propertyName);
        }

        OnErrorChanged(propertyName);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> _errors = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();

    public bool HasErrors => _errors.Values.Any(err => err != null);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName) => _errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) ? _errors[propertyName] : Enumerable.Empty<object>();

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    private void OnErrorChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

From the example, the `Number` property is supposed to be validated whenever `Limit` is changed, and validation errors for `Number` are supposed to be shown on the View. However, the validation method is observed to execute but no validation errors are shown for the `Number` field on the View.

From [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx), it seems like `INotifyDataErrorInfo` is supposed to support such cross-property validation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the binding engine expects that the `sender` of an `INotifyDataErrorInfo.ErrorsChanged` event to be the same object that the binding source resides in.

Changing

```
this._model.ErrorsChanged += (sender, args) => this.ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(sender, args);
```

To

```
this._model.ErrorsChanged += (sender, args) => this.ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
```

fixes the issue.

Any experts who knows why this is designed this way? (I spent one whole day just to troubleshoot this)

Comment: `BindingExpression` uses a `WeakEventManager` implementation to listen to the `INotifyDataErrorInfo.ErrorsChanged ` event. This manager acts like an aggregator. It registers the event handler of the `BindingExpression` using the event source (`ViewModel`) as lookup key. The manager then listens to the event. When the event is raised, the manager uses the event source (the sender) to lookup the corresponding event handler. Since the sender (`Model`) differs from the originally registered event source (`ViewModel`), the manager can't find a event handler and therefore can't deliver the event.

Comment: The described behavior is the default behavior for every `WeakEventManager` implementation.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks! Now I know at least why this is happening. Looks like the attempt to make non-leaking weak events has caused some unexpected side effects which is not documented.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. I think the way you have implemented your event delegation is what leads to unexpected side effects. You must always set the event source of an event to the actual class that the listeners are subscribing to. That's the only way that makes sense. The fact that the aggregated `Model` is the original source of an event are class internals and unknown to the subscriber. When you subscribe to an event of `ClassA`, then you would 100% expect the event source to be also `ClassA` and not some class' internal type. _This_ will lead to unexpected side effects for the listener.